# Can you be banned from a public theater for arguing with Supervisor?

Tags: constitutional-law

Movie tickets were purchased for a Halloween movie rated R including an adult ticket for a *chaperone*. The adult did not stay with high school students.

An employee makes it their mission to remove high school students without an adult present. They ask a police officer working at the theater to remove the 16-year-old students and in doing so, he uses physical force to push the student out.

Their parent gets a call that the 16 yr old was physically pushed out and gets upset. The parent questions the police officer about assault and was in turn asked to leave the theater.

The parent then called the local police to file a report and was told that the parent was banned from the theater.

Is that even possible? It is a public place, how does that even work? For questioning a police officer who was working at the theater why force was used?

Comment: movie tickets? That's not a public place but a private enterprise.

Comment: The story is a little unclear. Was the worker at the theater 16 and was that the same person as the “I” in the story?

Comment: I tried to clarify the situation, and made it less of a "I" story but general.

Comment: Related: [I was banned from a roller rink for something I didn’t say](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/41826/35069),
 [Can I be banned/barred from the mall for a year without being served papers?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/81315/35069), [Can I sue for being banned from the mall if I didn't do anything wrong?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/48522/35069), [Canary Wharf - privately owned public space - is it possible to be banned from entering the area?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/18465/35069)...

Comment: Also related: [Falsely Accused of Crime and Banned From Establishment](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/46563/35069), [Banned from the only store around](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/81797/35069)[closed] etc, etc...

Comment: In what jurisdiction did this take place?

Comment: @Trish: "Public place" and "private enterprise" are not mutually exclusive.  E.g. in [Indiana](https://cardellalawoffice.com/student-information/common-criminal-offenses-for-students/public-intoxication/public-place/): A public place is “any place where the public is invited and are free to go upon special or implied invitation a place available to all or a certain segment of the public.” Wright v. State, 772 N.E.2d 449 (Ind. App. 2002).  A movie theater certainly fits that.  Of course, it does not mean that a person can stay there once their invitation is revoked.

Comment: @NateEldredge that only would meet the *lobby* of the cinema in this case, not the actual theatre, for which you have to contract for admission - and here the enterprise's freedom of contract comes into place.

Comment: @Trish: "Public place" can include one that you have to pay to enter.  In [Utah](https://www.law.cornell.edu/regulations/utah/Utah-Admin-Code-R392-800-3): "Public place" means a place, facility, or location listed in Section 26-15-2 or Subsection 26-1-30(23) which may be an indoor or outdoor area, whether privately or publicly owned, to which persons not employed at the place have general and regular access by right or by invitation, expressed or implied, **whether by payment of money or not**".  And theaters and auditoriums are explicitly included further down.

Comment: So I don't think OP is wrong in saying that the movie theater is a public place, but I do agree it is not really relevant to the question of whether the children can be made to leave.

Comment: @Trish, it is black letter law that a theater is a public accommodation in the US.

Comment: How do you know you were banned for arguing?  It seems more likely that you would have been banned for skipping out as a chaperone...

Answer (score 4):

I’m guessing you have seen a sign in a business that read - “Management reserves the right to refuse service to anyone”.

At least in the US, they do not need a reason as long as the reason isn’t unlawful discrimination.

They can decide not to serve you.

Comment: I presume the presence of the sign isn't what creates this right, so it might be worth clarifying that they have that right, even if such a sign were not on display.

Comment: There’s a good chance that the sign was there. It might be worth clarifying that they have the right even if the customer doesn’t read the sign.

Answer (score 3):

It would be very rare that a movie theatre is a public place. 99.9% it is run by some company who has the right to ban people.

It seems they let in a child (16 year old is a child) under the condition that the child was accompanied by an adult. When the adult left they were allowed to and quite possibly required to remove the child. If the child refused to leave, they were allowed to remove the child with as much force as necessary, but not more. It seems that is what they did. It’s not assault. On the contrary, refusing to leave made the child a trespasser. Then you called the police, without any good reason, and of course the movie theatre doesn’t want you as a customer anymore. They banned you, which they are absolutely entitled to do.

Comment: By many definitions, a movie theater *is* a public place, see my comments on the question.  But it is still true that the owners can demand people to leave.